# InvalidCastException for Queue<String> in Multithreaded application

Tags: c#, string, exception, .net

**Output Buffer declared as a class variable**

```
private Queue<String> __OutputBuffer = new Queue<String>();
```

**Timer Used to Process Output every 100ms**

```
new System.Timers.Timer()
{
    Interval = 100,
    Enabled = true
}.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(
    (caller, args) =>
    {
        ProcessOutput();
    }
);
```

**Process the Queue**

```
private void ProcessOutput()
{
    if (__OutputBuffer.Count > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(__OutputBuffer.Peek()))
    {
        object _Item = __OutputBuffer.Dequeue();

        if(_Item is String)
        {
            try
            {
                Browser.DocumentText += "<span style='font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 9pt;'>" + _Item + "</span>"; 
                //Exception On Line Above!
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

**Method for adding to the output buffer**

```
private void UpdateOutput(String text)
{
    __OutputBuffer.Enqueue(text);
}
```

I'm getting invalid cast exception, and the following is the contents of _Item at the point of getting the exception.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GddT1Jj.png]

** Also the following causes an exception... so i'm doubting that it's the contents of the string in the queue.

[image]

Comment: `Queue<>` is not thread-safe, and `System.Timers.Timer` fires its events on a random pool thread, that's where `ProcessOutput` is called, and that's where you access `Browser.DocumentText`.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. I've used .Invoke on the Browser. Not sure if my solution is very good, please advise.

Comment: Why do you `Peek` then `Dequeue`?, if you ever have a empty string in your queue you would stop processing because it would never get dequeued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue<>` is not thread-safe, while `System.Timers.Timer` fires its events on a random pool thread. That's where `ProcessOutput` is called, and that's where you call `__OutputBuffer.Dequeue()` and access `Browser.DocumentText`.

You can protect `__OutputBuffer` from concurrent access with a `lock` (for both `Dequeue` and `Enqueue`), or use `ConcurrentQueue` instead. However, you'd need to marshal the `Browser.DocumentText` assignment to the UI thread, e.g. with `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: congrats on the 10K rep and thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As Noseratio said, `Queue<>` is not thread safe, however if you do not wish to use locking in your project and you are using .NET 4.0 or newer you can use the [`ConcurrentQueue<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is thread safe.

You will need to make a few changes, like there is no `Peek` nor `Dequeue` method instead you must use `TryPeek` and `TryDequeue`. But it should not require too many major changes, it even lets you do some optimisations because the two try methods will return `false` if the Queue is empty so you nolonger need the `Count` check.

```
private void ProcessOutput()
{
    string output;
    if (__OutputBuffer.TryDequeue(out output) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
    {
        try
        {
            Browser.DocumentText += "<span style='font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 9pt;'>" + output  + "</span>"; 
        }
        catch (Exception) { } // <--- Blindly catching exceptsions is almost never the right thing to do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Timer is considered Multithreaded.
you have a new thread every 100 ms, which may cause you to race condition on the dequeue

Use:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<String> __OutputBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<String>();

private void ProcessOutput()
{
    string _Item;
    if (__OutputBuffer.TryDequeue(out _Item))
    {
         try
         {
              Browser.DocumentText += "<span style='font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 9pt;'>" + _Item + "</span>";
             //Exception On Line Above!
         }
         catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```